# Java Bad path warning, and import error with my makefile

Tags: java, makefile, cygwin, jcommander

when I run my program I get the nexts errors:

```
$ make

JAVAC src/Document.java
warning: [path] bad path element "lib\jcommander.jar:lib\com": no such file or directory

1 warning

src\Menu.java:1: error: package com.beust.jcommander does not exist
import com.beust.jcommander.*;
```

The link of my repository and all the code is: https://bitbucket.org/IgnaMade/javasapp/src/da33bb2f63267d59c933e734b2155f78d037df31?at=master

In the fisrt line of the Menu.java I put:

```
import com.beust.jcommander.*;
```

The structure of the directories is:

In Lab2 there are the nexts directories:

src: that has all the .java's

bin: where all .txt's will be

lib: that has the jcommander.jar and the directory com

Makefile

Readme

The Makefile works with the path like this:

```
classpath:=$(lib_d)/jcommander.jar:$(lib_d)/com

# If there's already a CLASSPATH, put it on the front
ifneq ($(CLASSPATH),)
        classpath:= $(CLASSPATH):$(classpath)
endif

# Re-export the CLASSPATH.
export CLASSPATH:=$(classpath)
```

In Ubuntu it worked, but now I'm using windows and running on cygwin, and it doesn't work. I dont´t understand why.

Comment: You should remove `com` from that path. `classpath:=$(lib_d)/jcommander.jar:$(lib_d)/`, are you running on this on Windows? Your path separator doesn't appear to be consistent.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch thanks, It helps, but if I only remove com It still doesn't work, but if I remove     :$(lib_d)/com  it works.. This is an error or It's fine ? Yes, I'm runnig on Windows with cygwin, and In Ubuntu it worked.. my teacher is gone to work with Linux and I'm in problem if he can't run it.. How can I do to make a makefile that works with Ubuntu and Windows ?